# Bootstrap accordion "data-toggle" link force open (do not close!)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a solution to tell the `data-toggle="collapse"` link to open only. So if the box is already open (uncollapsed) there is no action required. I wonder if this option is contemplated for bootstrap (2.x) accordions by e.g. putting `uncollapse` or `open` instead of `collapse`. I have tried to guess but without luck.

Thanks for any help or hint! I am looking primarily for a solution without any additional JavaScript.

**edit**: I have to further explain that what I want to achieve is that I could add a link (button) which only opens, and another one that only closes the accordion. Sorry for not being specific enough

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 3's collapse component exposes a few events, see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events. The `hide.bs.collapse` event is fired if a section is being collapsed. You can listen to this event and simply `return false` to stop the collapse.

Bootstrap 2's collapse component seems to expose these events in a "non namespaced" manner, see http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse. It looks like you can listen to the `hide` event to achieve this, although I haven't tested it.

See this example for Bootstrap 3:

```js
$('#collapseOne').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  return false;
});
```

```css
#accordion {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this works wunderfully" There is one thing I think I didnt explain well: what I want to achieve is that I could add a link (button) which only opens, and another one that only closes the accordion. If I understand correctly, now the box is open for "eternety", right?

Comment: It indeed stays open for eternity. The event `hide.bs.collapse` doesn't get the target on which you clicked as an argument if I'm correct, otherwise you could use that to check the target and add another event to `show.bs.collapse` for the expand link. In your case it's probably best to not use _data attributes_ api but to use the JavaScript api instead, e.g. `$('#hide').click(function() { $('#section').collapse('hide'); });`

Answer (score 0):

I think what You can try accordtion to documentation is use `shown` event.

> "This event is fired when a collapse element has been made visible to
>   the user (will wait for css transitions to complete)."

Basicly You should do sth like here

```
$('#collapseBody').on('hidden', function () {
    var $toggle = $this.parents('.accordion-group').find('.accordion-toggle');

    $toggle.on('click', function(){
        return false;
    });
})
```

where `#collapseBody` is id of `div` with sample collapse content